# Question regarding Turpin-Coan algorithm (Byzantine Agreement Problem)

Tags: algorithms

I learned about Turpin-Coan algorithm for Consensus Agreement problems the other day, and I have a question regarding it.

the algorithm has 3 rounds. why is the second round necessary? I mean, what happens if we remove it? why would the algorithm fail?

I really hope for a good example here. Thanks!

Comment: Please include enough details about the algorithm so that readers don't have to go somewhere else to understand the question.